# ng-table: how to sort by a value which is not a part of ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

I'm using the ng-table directive which is quite nice but doesn't seem to have a proper documentation.
I can't find a way to sort by value which is not the column value. For example, consider this is the data I'm getting from the server:

```
 this.data = [ {'id': 1, 'gender': 'female', height: 170}, 
             {'id': 2, 'gender': 'male', height: 180}
    ];
```

here is the html:

```
<table dir='rtl' ng-table="service.tableParams">
  <tr ng-repeat="row in service.data">
     <td data-title="'gender'" sortable="'gender'">{{row.gender}}</td>
     <td data-title="'name'">{{ service.nameOf[row.id] }}</td>
     <td data-title="'height'" sortable="'height'">{{row.height}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

in the js file I have a map from id to a name:

```
nameOf = { 1: 'omer', 2: 'noam' };
```

My problem is with sorting by the name column. I want to sort by the nameOf[row.id] and not by the id.
Any idea how to do that?

Thanks,
Omer.

Comment: {{ row.name }} is not rather {{ nameOf[row.id] }} ?

Comment: Thanks, fixed it. any idea how to sort by it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work ;)

You have have to define yourself the manner of sort when he clicks on the sortable button.

```
getData: function($defer, params) {
        var orderedData;

        var sortByName = params.sorting().name
        if(sortByName) {
          orderedData = data.sort(function(a, b){
             var nameA=service.nameOf[a.id].toLowerCase(), nameB=service.nameOf[b.id].toLowerCase()
             if (nameA < nameB)
              return -1
             if (nameA > nameB)
              return 1
             return 0 
            });
            if (sortByName == 'desc') {
              orderedData = orderedData.reverse();
            }
        } else {
          orderedData = params.sorting() ?
                            $filter('orderBy')(data, params.orderBy()) :
                            data;
        }

        $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
    }
```

**Example** : [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/77uY00Dk1R6PMl60yJcd)

Comment: Why do you need the $ before the data parameter in the ng-repeat phrase?